# MS Access Query Expression in WHERE Clause

Tags: ms-access

I'm having trouble passing in a query expression into a WHERE clause. Access does not pick up the new column (expression) name and prompts me to entire a value for it. The simplified query is below.

You'll notice the second portion of the WHERE clause includes the [Offset] column name, which is what is causing me problems. The result should check if the DateAdd/Offset value (DATE) is before the one present in another table. Any ideas on how to handle this? Thank you!

```
  SELECT po.Item, 
  ist.SKU, 
  po.[EX-FACTORY DATE], 
  Min(lt.Intransit_LT) AS LT, 
  DateAdd('d',[LT],po.[EX-FACTORY DATE]) AS Offset

  FROM (((tbl_Item_PO AS po 

  LEFT JOIN tbl_ItemSKUType AS ist ON po.item = ist.Item) 
  LEFT JOIN Supplier_and_LT AS lt ON po.Supplier = lt.Supplier

  WHERE (((ist.SKU) Is Not Null) 
  AND ([Offset]<(select top 1 AOD from tbl_Date)))

  GROUP BY po.Item, ist.SKU, po.[EX-FACTORY DATE], po.[QTY PER SHIPMENT], po.WHSE, wh.Region, po.Ship_Method;
```

Edit: I have tried to put in the expression explicitly but I am then prompted for a value for [LT]. Seems like Access doesn't recognize column names other than those from the source tables

Edit: HAVING is now giving me a datatype mismatch in teh query expression error. HEre's what I'm working with:

```
 SELECT po.Item, 
 ist.SKU, 
 po.[EX-FACTORY DATE], 
 Min(lt.Intransit_LT) AS LT, 
 po.Ship_Method
 FROM (((tbl_Item_PO AS po 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_ItemSKUType AS ist ON po.item = ist.Item) 
 LEFT JOIN Supplier_and_LT AS lt ON po.Supplier = lt.Supplier
 WHERE (((ist.SKU) Is Not Null) 
 GROUP BY po.Item, ist.SKU, po.[EX-FACTORY DATE], po.[QTY PER SHIPMENT], po.WHSE, wh.Region, po.Ship_Method
 HAVING (DateAdd('d',MIN(lt.[Intransit_LT]),po.[EX-FACTORY DATE]))<(select top 1 AOD from tbl_Date)
```

Comment: Try to explicitly give the expression: `AND (DateAdd('d',[LT],po.[EX-FACTORY DATE])<(select top 1 AOD from tbl_Date)))`. Note that `Offset` is a keyword in many SQL dialects (just not JET/Ace SQL), so you should avoid using it as a column name, however, I'm not sure that caused your error.

Comment: Thank you but I did try this one too with the same problem. If I use the the expression explicitly, Access will prompt me for a value for [LT]. Not sure why?

Comment: Noticed another bad practice, you're using `As lt` for a table, and then `As LT` for a column. SQL generally doesn't look at capitalization, though it might not cause errors.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed this too when posting here and I'll change shortly. Hasn't caused any issues thus far but I did want to clean that up since it was unintentional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Offset` includes `LT`, and `LT` contains a `Min` aggregate expression. Aggregate expressions cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause, only in the `HAVING` clause.

Try the following:

```
  SELECT po.Item, 
  ist.SKU, 
  po.[EX-FACTORY DATE], 
  Min(lt.Intransit_LT) AS LT, 
  DateAdd('d',[LT],po.[EX-FACTORY DATE]) AS Offset

  FROM (tbl_Item_PO AS po 

  LEFT JOIN tbl_ItemSKUType AS ist ON po.item = ist.Item) 
  LEFT JOIN Supplier_and_LT AS lt ON po.Supplier = lt.Supplier

  WHERE (ist.SKU Is Not Null) 

  GROUP BY po.Item, ist.SKU, po.[EX-FACTORY DATE], po.[QTY PER SHIPMENT], po.WHSE, wh.Region, po.Ship_Method
  HAVING DateAdd('d',Min(lt.Intransit_LT),po.[EX-FACTORY DATE])<(select top 1 AOD from tbl_Date))
```

Comment: I tried to use HAVING but I am still prompted to enter the values.

Comment: Let's combine my solution with that of Gustav, then. See edit

Comment: I think we're getting closer but I'm getting an error now which says there is a data type mismatch in query expression. See edit..

Comment: Just checking the basics: `lt.Intransit_LT` is a valid numeric field? `[EX-FACTORY DATE]` is a valid date field? `AOD` is a valid date field? You can troubleshoot by using `HAVING DateAdd('d',1,Now())<(Now())` and fill your fields in one by one, to track down the field causing the bug. Also, try if it works if you replace your `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`. `LEFT JOIN` causes columns to be `Null`, and can cause these errors.

Comment: Yes, all fields are what they should be and none of the values are pulling in NULL (due to the nature of the data). I just built it up one-by-one and it's the MIN(lt.Intransit_LT) that is causing the problems. I can't imagine why Access can't recognize the number that pulls up...

Comment: Try wrapping that in a CInt (or CDbl if you're using decimals) to force Access to recognize it as a number. Note: going offline for a while, back tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
DateAdd('d',Min(lt.Intransit_LT),po.[EX-FACTORY DATE]) AS [Offset]

... 

WHERE ((ist.SKU Is Not Null) 
AND DateAdd('d',Min(lt.Intransit_LT),po.[EX-FACTORY DATE])<(select top 1 AOD from tbl_Date))
```